# Why do you think the 747 extended downwind to 6 miles?

Tags: boeing-747

1. Why the 747 extended downwind to 6 miles?
2. Why do you think Horizon turned 90 degrees to join the final?
3. What is the “rule” regarding Visual Approaches?

Comment: Not to be rude, but how do you expect anyone to provide an answer to what appears to be a specific incident if you don't provide any context or details?  Is this something you saw on Flightaware?  Is there a YouTube video, or incident report that is at the origin of your question?  We like to be helpful here, but you need to help us help you!  ;)

Comment: I doubt the horizon turned 90 degrees in a 747! Normal bank is 30, max. is 45!

Comment: @Bianfable, oh... I interpreted that as a separate Horizon airlines flight turning for 90 degrees of heading change.  Because we have Horizon airlines up here in the NW.  And because it was capitalized i assumed it was a company name...  (given the quality of the question I probably made the wrong assumption!)

Comment: @MichaelHall I didn't think of Horizon Airlines, maybe you're right :) That makes one more thing OP should clarify...

Answer (score 5):

1. For sequencing.
2. Because it was on a 90 degree base leg.
3. Look outside.